# How to use fivestar as sort criteria?

Tags: 6, views, rating

In Drupal 6, I have added fivestar widget to 'Story' nodes. Now I want to make a view to sort the stories according to their average fivestar ratings. But I don't see Fivestar among the 'Sort criteria', so how can I do the sorting based on Fivestar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, just enable the `top_content` default view which comes with the *VotingAPI* module. Its *Fivestar* display has the sorting set up as follows:

**Relationship:** Vote results
**Add sort criterion:** Vote results: Value, Relationship: Voting results

Comment: You don't have to configure anything. Once you've installed the modules and enabled the top_content view, at the pages /top-rated-points and /top-rated-percent there's the list of top rated content. Anyway, don't touch the relationship, have a look at the Vote results: Value Rating field and its formatting options.

Comment: This seems to actually sort on something other than the average vote... If a node has been voted on by many users, should I be able to sort the nodes by "average vote" using this method? If so It doesn't seem to be working.