# How to display the average rating of a node as stars in a view?

Tags: 7, views, rating

The users on my website can rate an article with the Fivestar module while they comment. I'd like to create a view with the 5 articles that have the highest average score.

I've nearly been able to achieve what I want with a 'Vote results' relationship and a 'Vote results: Value' field. The problem is that the average score is displayed as a number, but I'd rather like it to be shown as stars. I achieved this in the past without custom coding (thanks to a deleted video that was situated [here](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/video/building-views-fivestar-and-votingapi)), but I forgot how to do it.

Can you help?

Comment: This has it for Drupal 6:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/how-to-use-fivestar-as-sort-criteria; I'd assume something similar is the case for Drupal 7

Comment: @Jimajamma: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, I've tried the 'Vote results' relationship too, but as you can read in my updated question, it didn't solve my problem completely.

Comment: Ah!  What you will have to do there is find out where in Views it is outputting that score/number and then feed that into the Five Star theme function that generates the stars from that number.

Comment: @Jimajamma: You're right. I think I succeeded in doing that in the past (only using the Views UI), but I can't remember how I did it... That's why I eventually started this question.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any D7 systems with 5star loaded on them to try to dig into it, but between the theme templates that the Views UI allows you to change and the theme functions in 5star, I am sure you'll be able to figure it out!

Comment: ....but looking on D6, when you click on the `Vote results: value` field in the fivestar view display of top_content, you can change the appearance right there to be any number of 5 star themed values....

Comment: @Jimajamma: I'd expect it to be possible right there too, but apparently it changed in D7, because I don't have that option (not even in `top_content`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally rediscovered how I achieved this in the past. First, follow each step in [this article](https://drupal.org/node/1308114/revisions/6684209/view) and call the Fivestar field 'Stars'. Next, import the following view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'best_content';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Best content';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Vote results */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['id'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['field'] = 'votingapi_cache';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['required'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['votingapi_cache']['votingapi'] = array(
  'value_type' => 'percent',
  'tag' => 'vote',
  'function' => 'average',
);
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Field: Stars */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['id'] = 'field_stars';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['table'] = 'field_data_field_stars';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['field'] = 'field_stars';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['click_sort_column'] = 'rating';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_stars']['settings'] = array(
  'widget' => array(
    'fivestar_widget' => 'sites/all/modules/fivestar/widgets/basic/basic.css',
  ),
  'expose' => 0,
  'style' => 'average',
  'text' => 'none',
);
/* Sort criterion: Field: Stars (field_stars:rating) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_stars_rating']['id'] = 'field_stars_rating';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_stars_rating']['table'] = 'field_data_field_stars';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_stars_rating']['field'] = 'field_stars_rating';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_stars_rating']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
```

Done!

---

PS: [This comment](https://drupal.org/comment/8648919#comment-8648919) might explain why this didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

Create a Views template for this specific field and put it in your theme (or module if you have Views templates already there and enabled via the Views api hook).

In my case it was called `views-view-field--top-content--page-1--value.tpl.php` for just the included and now enabled top content View.

In there, do the following:

```
<?php
  $data = $row->{$field->field_alias};
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'fivestar');
  print theme('fivestar_static', array('rating' => $data, 'widget' => array('name' => 'basic', 'css' => $path . '/widgets/basic/basic.css')));
?>
```

And if all is well in the world of copy and paste, you should now have a View with basic stars displayed instead of the number.  If you don't like the basic stars, just look in the widgets directory and you can take your pick of any of the other styles there.